# Firebase Phone Auth won't send me the sms with my code

Tags: android, ios, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I migrated my app from using Digits Phone Auth to the new Firebase Phone Auth but while I was testing my app I had troubles signing out my user (Already fixed that) so I just deleted it from the "User list" on the console but now every time I try to sign in with that phone number it won't send me the sms with my code, it works fine with any other number but this one. Does someone knows how can I fix this?

Comment: Got my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53513327/1713519

Answer (score 52):

I had the same issue. It was because of adding my phone number to test phone numbers at the firebase console. Remove it from "test devices" section.)

Comment: Thanks! wasted hours on it

Comment: @kazimad, I am having a similar issue. Where can I find "test devices" on the console??

Comment: @Shammir it is under Firebase console, Auth, Sign-in method, Phone, Phone numbers for testing (optional) .

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey @kazimad , I just do that but I can't receive anything - in a Testing mode "Debugging" you know we write a test verify code and it's work well but after I release my app for Stores I can't get any SMS So should I do something maybe I forget?

Comment: I have not put my number in testing devices. but I have put different numbers. still I am not getting sms. Also when I try from an android device a sms does not come. but from a iPhone it comes.

Answer (score 7):

First check the log, if `onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential cred)` is called or not. If called then this might be the cases:

**EDIT: I had answered the question assuming android environment. These two cases are relevant to android programming only.**

- Instant verification: in some cases the phone number can be instantly verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
- Auto-retrieval: on some devices, Google Play services can automatically detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without user action. (This capability might be unavailable with some carriers.).
  In above cases the the verification process is handled automatically without you needing to enter the code.

Else this might be the case:

> To prevent abuse, Firebase enforces a limit on the number of SMS messages that can be sent to a single phone number within a period of time. If you exceed this limit, phone number verification requests might be throttled. If you encounter this issue during development, use a different phone number for testing, or try the request again later.

Refer [Authenticate with Firebase on Android using a Phone Number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) for more information.

Comment: I'm developing this app for iOS so theres no instant verification, and I know it's working and sending the SMS because it's working with any other phone number except mine. I waited a day before trying and again thinking that probably I had reach the maximum tries per day, but that didn't work either. The console doesn't give any logs so I'm totally lost here. Maybe Firebase banned my number? I asked on the firebase slack and the forum but no one seems to answer. I'm using FirebaseUI btw.

Comment: Yeah, sorry the doc was for android but the third scenario is same for ios as well as android. It seems like you must have exceeded the limit. And if this is the issue, the documentation also says that use a different phone number for testing, or try the request again later(but doesn't say how much later).

Comment: It was probably that I had exceeded the limit because now is working, thanks for the help!

Comment: <#> ExampleApp: Your code is 5664
   r64Iw/6mD1D

I want my code in this formet is it possible?

Comment: @VajaniKishan Not sure if it's possible but looks like you are trying to achieve OTP autofill here with that hash code. I reckon, from this source https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/firebase-authentication-with-phone-number-otp-in-android/, we don't need this format to achieve that while using Firebase phone auth. Maybe Firebase handles it by default.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you added your phone number as s test phone number as below and delete it, if it in test numbers:
1- go to firebase console and select your project, then select `Authentication`
[image]

2-got to phone provider
[image]

3- go down to phone numbers which adds as test numbers and delete your phone number from this list:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed my initial loading activity to logout activity through `AndroidManifest` file. Here is the final version:

```
<activity android:name=".OtpActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainPageActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

`MainPageActivity` was my Logout Activity.